# does pthread join really suspends calling thread

Tags: c, join, pthreads

I have seen working examples like following in main

```
pthread_t sa[12];
for(i=0;i<12;i++)
   pthread_create(&sa[i],NULL,&matrix_mult,NULL);
for(i=0;i<12;i++)
    {   if(sa[i]!=(int)NULL)
        {   pthread_join(sa[i],NULL);
        }
    }
```

Does this mean that main ends when all pthreads have terminated ?
Actually , I was writing a code in which sa[3] ended before sa[0]
so I added

```
pthread_join(sa[0],NULL);
```

in end of function for sa[3]
hoping that sa[3] will terminate only after sa[0] has ended .
It did not happen .
Where am I thinking wrong ?

Comment: If you really do have a `pthread_join(sa[0], NULL)` at the end of the the `sa[3]` proc (which I assume was somehow uniquely invoked from `matrix_mult`), then `sa[0]` really has no business being in this join sequence *at all*. it should be handed off to `sa[3]` (somehow) and not included in the join sequence here (i.e. start the sequence at `1`). It looks like you have a race condition on the unprotected `sa[0]` between the join  from `sa[3]` and this join loop. Someone is going to lose, and I'm guessing this loop is probably your frequent winner.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that main ends when all pthreads have terminated ?

Yes.

> Actually , I was writing a code in which sa[3] ended before sa[0]

That's certainly possible. But main thread waits for s[0]. s[1], .. and so on. It doesn't mean, when main waits for s[0], s[3] couldn't complete execution.

> in end of function for sa[3] hoping that sa[3] will terminate only after sa[0] has ended . It did not happen.

There's absolutely no ordering about which threads complete execution first or last etc. Any thread could complete execution at any time. What the pthread_join() calls in main ensures is that main thread waits for the completion of *all* the threads before proceeding.

When main thread is waiting on thread `s[x]` (`pthread(s[x], NULL);`), thread `s[y]` completes execution then main thread will still continue to wait on `s[x]`. At some point when main thread calls `pthread_join(s[y], NULL);`, `pthread_join()`
will return *immediately* because the thread `s[y]` has already completed execution.

In short, pthread_join() calls *do not* ensure any sort of thread execution ordering. It simply suspends the calling thread until the thread its called on returns (completes execution).

Comment: Note: [per the specification of `pthread_join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html),"The results of multiple simultaneous calls to pthread_join() specifying the same target thread are undefined" and "The behavior is undefined if the value specified by the thread argument to `pthread_join()` does not refer to a joinable thread.". In short, don't bank on any defined behavior if you have two `pthread_join` calls on the same thread handle. You won't get it.